# How do I setup authentication on a specific folder using .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, authentication

I have a folder that I want to host files privately on my webserver.

How do I go about making it password protected using .htaccess?

*Note: Nothing monolithic, I want something that is simple/easy so setup so me and a few colleagues can download a few files.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a file called `.htpasswd` with the content of `username:password` (you should encrypt that.

Then append this to the `htaccesss file`:

```
AuthUserFile /usr/local/you/safedir/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName EnterPassword
AuthType Basic

require user username
```

Follow [this guide](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess3.shtml).

Also, here is a tool for generating the encrypted passwords: http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password (Thanks to the original poster for the link)

Comment: Thanks. Could you add this link in your answer too? http://www.tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/. It's the password encryption tool from DynamicDrive.

Answer (score 1):

### install htpasswd (password generator)

install apache2-utils through

```
sudo apt-get install apache2-utils
```

This above package has htpasswd command.

### configure basic authentication

go to apache2.conf file and edit

1. change "AllowOverride none" to "AllowOverride All" to .htaccess enable and working in the directory.
2. add a new line below the above edit lines "AllowOverride AuthConfig"
   to enable apache2 to handle authentication. keep in mind these modules should be enables

   1. authn_core_module
   2. authz_core_module

you can check these modules (enable or not) through this command

```
sudo apache2ctl -M
```

### create password file(create new user and password)

1. create your folder in /var/www/html/

   `sudo mkdir -m /var/www/html/my_protected_folder`
2. `htpasswd -c /var/www/html/my_protected_folder/.htpassword username` and enter prompted password. .htpassword file created with username and encrypted password.

   3. crate .htaccess file with these content 

      `AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Restricted Access"
      AuthUserFile /var/www/html/my_protected_folder/.htpassword
      Require user username`

### change permission and ownership

1. `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/my_protected_folder`
2. `sudo chmod 660 /var/www/html/my_protected_folder/.htpassword`

visit your page and enter username "username" and password which you wrote.