# Is there a simple way to protect my webpage by password?

Tags: html, password, protection

I am writing some simple HTML pages. I need to protect some pages and some files (from being downloaded) by requiring a username and password. Does anyone know a simple solution?

Comment: What sort of webserver are you using? Apache? IIS?

Comment: I don't know actually. I can connect to the server to upload my files there. Besides that, I don't think that I could have other access to the server. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to use Netcraft as suggested in this question http://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using to work it out and then tell us the results.

Comment: Here is the result: Thank you! 

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 10 May 2011 10:14:35 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.52 (Red Hat)
X-Powered-By: PHP/4.3.9
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: To make this question useful to other people I've answered it for people using IIS too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all find out what sort of webserver you are using by using the method suggested in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/120783/can-i-detect-what-webserver-a-website-is-using

**If it's Apache**
[How do I setup authentication on a specific folder using .htaccess?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/282/how-do-i-setup-authentication-on-a-specific-folder-using-htaccess)

**If it's IIS**
https://serverfault.com/questions/193273/iis-password-protection-for-php

Comment: Dear Paulmorriss, thank you very much for your great help. Is solves my problem. :-)