# Hide a file showing up in google search

Tags: google-search, url, search-engine-indexing, iis7, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to protect PDF file from indexing?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14520/how-to-protect-pdf-file-from-indexing)

Hi guys,

Really basic question here I'm sure - I'm not a webmaster however am thrown into it sometimes!!

We have a particular file this is available for download on our site, however this file shows up in a Google search. My manager wants to make this file hidden from google if possible. Can anybody point me in the right direction for this?

Right now the file is sitting with the following URL:

> `http://www.example.com/document.pdf`

The site is running on IIS7.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide it from Google (and other search engines who use it) you need to create a robots.txt file (if you don't have one already) and add a line to exclude that document. For more information see http://www.robotstxt.org/.

Another way is to password protect it and make sure that the web page that points to the document says what the username and password is. See this question for how to do that:
[Is there a simple way to protect my webpage by password?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13580/is-there-a-simple-way-to-protect-my-webpage-by-password)

Comment: Hi @paulmorriss. Thanks for the reply. There didn't appear to be a robots.txt file in the directory so I will put one in there. Thanks for your help.